# Magento checkout IE 7 and Safari

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

When using IE 7 or Safari and a customer clicks checkout and fills in the form on Magento. If they select credit card payment and click place order Magento just goes back to the product page and does not proceed to cc payment details.

This only happens in IE 7 or Safari. Anyone know where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Check your error logs.  In your browser, check your Javascript errors around that time.  In Magento, set Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Log Settings -> Enabled: Yes.

Re-create the error and then check var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log.